# Intern: DRY Runners for multiple project in one workspace

Tags: node.js, browser, requirejs, configuration-files, intern

While realizing that my project setup might be the root cause of my problem, here's what I'd like some help with (moving from another framework to [Intern](https://theintern.github.io/)):

I've different (>20) projects in one dev workspace, so I've (>20) different directories with test code. I'd like a project to be testable on itself, but also would like to execute all suites together.
I am specifying to use RequireJS as an AMD loader and where my tests can be found per project (one for nodeJS, one for browsers) through a config file. *PLUS* I have one overall config file specifying *all* the files.

**You can image there is quite the duplication, what would be a good approach to DRY this up?**

Note: it would also be welcome to help to describe my problem better (more generic or less TLDR)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Intern configuration files are just AMD modules you can use the normal dependency loading mechanism to load and combine configuration data from multiple files:

```js
// in your “do everything” master configuration
define([
  'projectA/tests/intern',
  'projectB/tests/intern',
  'projectC/tests/intern',
  // …
], function () {
  var configs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  function getCombined(key) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], configs.map(function (config) {
      return config[key];
    }));
  }

  return {
    suites: getCombined('suites'),
    functionalSuites: getCombined('functionalSuites'),
    // …
  };
});
```

Comment: Oh how could I not have seen this! Thanks!